# Write to STM32 internal flash fails

Tags: memory, stm32, flash-memory

On my stm32 mcu there is no eeprom. So, I am using internal flash to save one byte user data to retain it between power cycles.I am doing it the following way,

1. Add Data section in memory in the linker script

```
MEMORY { 
   RAM (xrw) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 8K 
   FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x8000000, LENGTH = 64K 
   DATA (xrw) : ORIGIN = 0x800F800, LENGTH = 2K //Allocated one full flash page 
}
```

2. Create user data section

```
    .user_data : 
     { . = ALIGN(4); 
       *(.user_data)
       . = ALIGN(4);
     } >DATA
```

3. Create a variable to store in flash

```
    attribute((section(".user_data"))) const uint8_t userConfig[10]
```

4. Write data using following functions,

```
    HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
    
    __HAL_FLASH_CLEAR_FLAG(FLASH_FLAG_EOP | FLASH_FLAG_OPERR | FLASH_FLAG_WRPERR | FLASH_FLAG_PGAERR | FLASH_FLAG_PGSERR );
    
    FLASH_PageErase(FLASH_PAGE_31);
    
    HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_DOUBLEWORD, (uint32_t)&userConfig[index], someData);
    
    HAL_FLASH_Lock();
```

When I try to write to the flash it fails with PGSERR flag set.

Comment: which stm32 they are not all the same

Comment: @old_timer I am using stm32G031K8

Comment: format your question to be reader friendly. I edited it to show you one example

Comment: Thanks @P__JsupportswomeninPoland. Edited my question for better readability

Comment: do not change question as answers stop to make sense. Add some explanation to the question, but do not change it!

Answer (score 0):

1. `0x0800 3800 - 0x0800 3FFF` is bank 7 not bank 11.
2. `&userConfig[index]` is generally wrong as the memory is programmed in this micro in 64bits words and the address has to be aligned to the 8 bytes boundary.

**ALWAYS READ THE DOCUMENTATION** before programming microcontrollers. Use of the ***magic*** libraries does not free you from knowing your hardware.

Comment: 1. That was a typo.corrected it in the question

2. What would be the correct way?